# An alternative of software like VisualVM to programmatically find running java applications' values etc. by searching heap dumps?

Tags: java, memory, pointers, static, visualvm

I'm not experienced with java applications but I found out that finding static pointers etc. to these applications' memory addresses is often (nearly) impossible, apparently because of the java engine that handles the code (correct me if this way of naming it is wrong please).

Now, I've used VisualVM (https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) and it's great. I can select my java process and create a heap dump. It then shows me all classes and their values.

Can I use this method to continousely poll the heap dump and receive object values, for example the X Y and Z of a game? How would I programmatically interact with such application, and if this should not be done with VisualVM, what would be an alternative?

**Edit: this is what I need to do:**
I need to be able to find all classes with properties that have a certain value. For example: I'd search for the X coordinate (a float) and it should return the class "PlayerCoordsHandler" (just an example) and the corresponding float with it's value... or alternatively just a way to find this same float again (after restarting for example). This process does not have to be programmatic, aslong as requesting the value of the now known property (x float) can be retrieved programmatically (for example with a command line utility or reading from a file).

**Edit2:**
The target application is a windows executable (but made with java) and launches it's own java VM. It's not possible to add java parameters for debugging. This does not seem to be required though, as VirtualVM is able to debug the process just fine. Anyone knows how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is crazy, people read "VisualVM" and they just jump in with their YourKit, MAT, mine is better that yours, etc without answering the real question. Tom, could you clarify what you are trying to do, I really don't think that generating heap dumps is the way to go.

Comment: @Pascal: My mentioning of MAT was just a generic alternative as you can see me and a few others also suggests that Tom creates an MBean or something where he can either publish the values as attributes or have an operation to look specific values up if that is more practical. What is so crazy with that? An alternative could of course be to not use JMX but create some other interface to do the same but then Tom will have to write a lot of things JMX takes care of anyway. He asked for alternatives for a very vague need and he got them. Nothing crazy with that.

Comment: All answers so far were more than helpful! I understand that my question might be quite vague but for someone unexperienced with all the terms in this field this is the best I can do.

Comment: @Tom: Is it a set of well defined parameters you want to look at or something more complex?

Comment: I updated my question with an example of what I need to do. I think it's a well defined parameter (?)

Comment: @Tom: I edited my post slightly. SO doesn't have a very good PM function but if I forget to extend it more, please comment on that post to remind me.

Comment: Thanks, I commented your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to debug running Java applications.

The "official" Java debugger is JDB. I believe it's part of the JDK. It has the ability to set breakpoints, examine heaps, list and display and even change variables, show running threads and so on. The usual debugger stuff. But it's command line, which makes it a pain in the neck to work with.

Instead, it makes a lot of sense to use an IDE with integrated debugger. I use Eclipse. You can do all the usual debuggery things, including displaying windows with variables. You can set conditional breakpoints and there's much more. Specifically in answer to your question, you can set up watch expressions, which will be evaluated during the program's execution and their displays refreshed with new values when they change.

You may not want to run your Java app inside the IDE; or it may be running in a Web application server. That's no problem for JDB or Eclipse (or other IDEs, like NetBeans or IntelliJ Idea): They can connect to a running JVM and debug remotely with the same level of convenience.

A program being debugged like this, remotely or otherwise, run somewhat more slowly than if it were not. Your game, while being debugged, will run at rather bad-looking FPS; but it should still respond more or less normally to gameplay interaction.

---

#### Remote debugging:

> To be able to attach your <s>Eclipse</s>NetBeans debugger to a running Java process you need to start that process with the following Java options…

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=3704,server=y,suspend=n
```

Comment: Alright, it seems like I shouldn't use heap dumps but use these debugging tools to access the values directly. I will try to do this with the proposed applications. Would there be a way to automate this and retreive the output from command line or a text file?

Comment: Yes. As JDP is a command line utility reading commands from standard input I would think you'd be able to automate its operation. I don't have any experience with this, though.

Comment: Update: For the requirement stated in the update to your question, you may need some programmatic help. i.e. If you could set up a static or at least unique object inside your game code that knows to find those other objects you're looking for and then have references to them in fields of its own, then the debugging part of the task will be much, much easier.

Comment: I read at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html : "Another way to use jdb is by attaching it to a Java VM that is already running. A VM that is to be debugged with jdb must be started with the following options: ..." The application is not run with these parameters and I cannot do so either. Is that a problem?

Comment: @ Carl's update: Unfortunately I do not have access to the application's source.

Comment: Just tried debugging with NetBeans. It returns: "Attaching to pid=3704
Not a debuggee, or not listening for debugger to attach". It is indeed not a debugger and I can not set it to be one if I do not own the source, right? How does VisualVM manage to debug it regardless?

Comment: Hey Carl, afraid you missed the "The application is not run with these parameters and I cannot do so either"-part. I am not launching this application manually, it's actually a windows executable using C++, java and other things combined. With VisualVM I can simply select the process and it does the job without adding any parameters.

Comment: Oh I see. This is starting to look non-trivial. You could probably still trick it by removing the "real" `java` from the classpath and replacing it with a `java.cmd` or `java.bat` that calls the real one with the required options. But if that don't work I'm afraid it would be time to give up on this approach. :(

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning this earlier. Didn't think it was relevant because VirtualVM can simply debug the app. Too bad it's only creating heap dumps. Maybe that's why. I'm afraid I have no idea how to trick it the way you're suggesting either. Thanks a lot for all the help though.

Comment: Do make a serious attempt at running a "fake" Java. I just remembered that it's possible to command-line inject a "startup" class from outside a Java program, and if it could be done this would open the door to all kinds of kinky debug assists.

Comment: I do not see any java files though (it's all bundled into an .exe, so not accepting any java specific parameters). I do know the location of the JRE the application is using, does that help?

Comment: Yes. I sure hope I'm not wasting your time on a wild goose chase. The idea is, remove that JRE's `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` from system PATH (you could just rename them if you wanna be brutal) and put a `java.CMD` and `javaw.CMD` file on the path that will call the renamed java `exe`s under the new name. If you can get that working you've got Java by the tail. I keep mentioning both java.exe and javaw.exe cause your app could be using either. Javaw is normally for GUI apps.

Comment: Well the application is calling java.exe and not java.CMD. I can not  modify it to call java.CMD instead of java.exe right?

Comment: Update: it appears that java.exe and javaw.exe are not used at all as the game runs fine after deleting them. Java.dll is in use however, not sure about other files.

Comment: Update2: client/jvm.dll is also being used. How would one process parameters to the JVM when it's not launched by an executable but loaded into the application with DLLs?

Comment: Honest answer: I'm out of my depth and give up. Sorry!

Comment: No problem. :P I am at that stage too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Triggering a heapdump is usefull for post-mortem analysis of say memory leaks, but as the Java garbage collector moves objects around, you cannot use the memory values of a heapdump to reliably access those objects.

<strike>If you need a way to query internal values from outside of the application you could look into setting up an RMI service API via which you can retrieve the values you need.</strike>

Another method (if you just need to test something) could be to connect to the process via de Java debugging API.

If you know the JRE location that is used, you could rename java.exe and write a (C/C++) wrapper that adds the debug options listed by Carl and calls the renamed_java.exe in turn.

Another posibility might be to add or update classes in the `.jar` file of the application. You do not need the source to do this.

Tom, are you trying to reverse engineer an application that specifically tries to obfuscate its working? If so you might get further if you contact the manufacturer and ask them what possibilities they see for what you try to achieve?

Comment: Just to help Tom and me keep track of which solutions are in the running: I'm afraid recent updates of his have put RMI out of the question (no source to muck with) and remote debugging (probably) too (no access to the JVM command line).

Comment: Unfortunately the app runs fine when the java exes are removed. There is also no java process active, and I can't find a java service either. However, the java.dll file in the JRE folder is used and visualVM can see the application. It also verifies that my JRE folder location is correct, it just doesn't seem to be using the java executables.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/). You can monitor CPU, memory and threads live, and generate dumps whenever you want. It can even compare different memory dumps to show you which objects were added/removed.

It's not free though, it has a 15 day (or 30 day?) fully functional eval period. If free is not a real concern it's definitely a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

I good starting point is the [`jps`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) and [`jstat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html) tools added in Java 6 (i think). `jps` gives you the pid and main class for each application. `jstat` give you more details about process

Answer (score 2):

You can easily generate a heap dump by creating your own JMX connection to the JVM, just like VisualVM does it. Analyzing the heapdump is very possible (the data is there and totally disconnected from the JVM so there is no interference from the gc).

However, unless it is a very specific scenario you are looking for you are probably much better off giving the heapdump to [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and find a good workflow in there to use.

**Edit:** In this particular case it is probably better to create some kind of specific API to access the values from the outside (and maybe publish the values as MBeans using JMX). Taking a heap dump is way to much work if all you want to do is monitoring a few values.

**Edit2:** Based on your edits, it seems to me like you could really benefit from publishing your own MBean over JMX. I have to run for a meeting but, unless someone else does it while I am away, I will try to remember to give you some pointers later. Either in an edit of this one or in a new post.

Comment: That'd be great. I indeed only want to monitor values. I'd appreciate help on how to do the MBean over JMX approach to receive values from the outside of an application connected to a JVM.

Comment: With from the outside I mean that it's not my application, but still on the same system of course. I don't have to access a different remote connection or something, if that is why you want to use JMX. If not, please ignore this message.

Comment: @Tom, let me see if I get it right. The application you want to monitor is not yours but still you know enough about its inner workings to look at variable values? It could very well be doable even if it is not your app but I wonder if it is worth the effort.

Comment: I think you got that right. For example a game will always have a player object (well most of them). One could retreive the coordinate parameters (values) of this object from the JVM and use it to automate things within the game. I just need to be able to search for values and then access that object's values all the time. By looking at what VisualVM can do, that seems possible. Normally one would use static pointers for memory addresses. However, because of the JVM this does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to poll the values of specific objects while your Java application is running you would probably find that using [JMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) is a better and more efficient approach rather than using a heap dump. With JMX you can define what values should be exposed and use tools such as VisualVM or JConsole to view them at runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure. Depends on whether the application has an API available to access what you need. I guess you could create MBeans to call the API but there could be an issues with registering the MBeans on startup. You would probably need to create your own Java code to do this then launch the existing application. Again, no idea if this is possible without knowing what he does have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

With VisualVM and heapdump you can find all classes with certain property by OQL:

```
var out = "";
var cls = filter(heap.classes(), "/java./(it.name)")

while (cls.hasNext()) {
  var cl = cls.next();
  var fls = cl.fields;
  while (fls.hasMoreElements()) {
    var fl = fls.nextElement();
    if (/size/(fl.name)) {
      out = toHtml(cl) + "." + fl.name + "()\n";
    }
  }
}

out.toString()
```

and write custom logging for [BTrace](https://kenai.com/projects/btrace)

It is alternative for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

FusionReactor could be a good alternative. For example;

> VisualVM doesn’t give you a lot of insides on application memory
> except for the total Heap allocation. Heap is a good metric to start
> with, but I feel this is not enough to troubleshoot the actual cause
> of a memory-related issue.

> FusionReactor will display all of the memory spaces it detects, which
> depends on the version of Java you’re running:
>
> Heap allocation Non-Heap allocation CodeHeap (profiled and
> non-profiled methods) Compressed Class Space FusionReactor also shows
> the amount of memory that each generation takes Eden Space Old Space
> Survivor Space

https://www.fusion-reactor.com/blog/java-visualvm-alternatives/